# Method to pass arguments to a procedure in oracle database

Tags: java, oracle

code in jsp page

```
cs=conn.prepareCall("{call held('"+session.getAttribute("roll")+"')}");
                        cs.executeUpdate();
```

in oracle database procedure is as

```
create or replace procedure "Held"
(s in Varchar2)
    l_col_name varchar2(30);
begin
    SELECT SUBJECTCODE 
    into l_col_name
    FROM table02 
    WHERE SERIALNUMBER = '1';

    execute immediate
        'UPDATE TABLE01 SET '|| l_col_name || ' = '
              || l_col_name || ' + 1 WHERE Rollno = s'
    ;
end;
```

the following is the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "S": invalid identifier ORA-06512: at "ROHIT.HELD", line 12 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

please rectify it

i am trying to take the value of session ie from code in jsp and trying to use it in oracle database ....
i have used s as variable to store that value and used it in where clause

suggest a solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the jsp side is correct, but you clearly have a bug in your procedure.

> When ORA-00904 occurs, you must enter a valid column name as it is
>   either missing or the one entered is invalid.

Here, your statement `WHERE Rollno = s` is understand as 'where column rollno is equal to column s', but the column s doesn't exist. I suppose you just have to move `s` out of the string.

```
execute immediate
    'UPDATE TABLE01 SET '|| l_col_name || ' = '
          || l_col_name || ' + 1 WHERE Rollno = ''' || s || ''''
;
```

Comment: yes u are right s is not a column.......................but i need to retrive the value of session through which i have logged in ..the session is actually a value of column roll nos .....so now how should i proceed

Comment: @user3738332 See my edit, you wasn't using the `s` argument but a raw character ;)